# How should I push the time/date from a host to clients (Isolated from the internet)

Tags: bash, date, ubuntu, time

I have a host machine, and I need to set the time on 2-3 clients so they match the host. This is being done with an initialization script (in lu with other tasks.)

NTP has proven to be unreliable, since all machine are isolated from GPS time and the web. Also, these machines do not have RTC, they do not maintain time while powered off.

What is the best way to push the host's time to them?

Right now i'm reading into using timedatectl -H , but i'm open to ideas.
*ubuntu 16.04*

Comment: I'm not sure that NTP is the problem, as it should be able to keep your clients in sync with your host just fine. The real problem appears to be that your host simply isn't keeping in step with what you think the real time should be.

Comment: I'm not saying NTP is the problem, I'm saying that it isn't relevant. Since the clients do not have RTC, they will drift past the 1000s threshold of NTP when they are powered off.

What I need is a one-shot push that sets the clients time to the hosts time.

Everyone seems to love NTP, and it is great for clients with web access and RTC. But these machines do not have web access, or RTC. But they need to all have the same timestamp, give or take a second.

Comment: They don't *need* web access; they just need access to your host, and they just need to be configured to run NTP when they first start. I don't see what you think another solution will do that NTP doesn't.

Comment: My issue with NTP is that it doesn't sync quickly enough when RTC has drifted much. (even with iburst)

My long term solution is to use NTP and add an RTC battery to these devices. But for now, I was hoping someone would have a quick/dirty way to set the time on clients via bash, or some other implementation.

Comment: OK, it sounds like in your case, you need a roughly accurate response *now*, rather than a very accurate response *soon*. (NTP does some work to predict what time it will be when the client gets its response, and sends *that* time, rather than the *current* time.) It might be possible to configure `ntpd` to be faster at the expense of accuracy, but I'm not the one to provide such an answer.